# Is it possible to create an Ingress resource on a GKE cluster and force it to use an existing HTTP(S) load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy my infra on GCE and I host UI using GCP Storage Buckets and Backend APIs using a GKE cluster. I already deployed my front-end apps and added a load balancer to route requests to the UI bucket. I would like to use the same load balancer for the API traffic as well. I am wondering if it is possible to use one single load balancer for both workloads. When I create an Ingress resource on a GKE cluster, a new HTTP(S) load balancer gets automatically created as explained in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress). Is it possible to create an Ingress rule which only adds a HTTP rule to an existing load balancer but does not create a new load balancer?

Comment: No, what you ask is not possible. You'd better use Nginx Ingress with Load Balancer for everything you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your service to a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/) (Change the type `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort`)

Then, you can create a new backend in your loadbalancer, select your Instance Group (your node pool), and set the correct port.

It should work.

Comment: Ok. I will try this out but sounds like this might be tricky to automate. I manage infra using terraform. So, when I create a new service on k8s I then have to run the terraform again to create the backend and also create a forwarding rule. I was hoping that the complete lifecycle is managed by ingress controller itself. It would be nice to have something like that. Anyway thanks for your answer. I will try it out today.

Comment: Understood, the best way is to simply deploy a YAML file with kubectl to make the set up. Open a feature request for this, it's an interesting use case. Maybe a CRD could do this. I don't yet dig into CRD to be sure.